# Know type of derived class of base pointer in an argument inside a function?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have a class `Attribute`

```
class Attribute {};
```

which is base class of some classes like

```
class Place : public Attribute {};
class Time : public Attribute {};
class Way: public Attribute {};
```

Then I have two initializer_lists

```
Place* place = new Place();
Time* time = new Time();
Way* way = new Way();
auto il1 = std::initializer_list<Attribute*>({ place, time });
auto il2 = std::initializer_list<Attribute*>({ place, way });
```

My goal is to know the elements of the initializer list which are of type of the elements of the second `initializer_list`.

One way of doing it is doing something like

```
bool isFirstElementAPlace = (dynamic_cast<Place*>(*(l.begin())) ? true : false);
```

But `Place*` should be replaced with `typeid(*(il2.begin()))`, but the type info returned by it is `Attribute*`, not `Place*` or so. So this answer is not valid.

---

Is there a way to generically know the type of the derived class of a pointer of a base class inside an argument of an initializer_list?

**SOLVED IN [THIS QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41909680/existing-types-should-be-replaced-new-types-added-to-it)**

Comment: [std::type_info](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info)?

Comment: Explain your question in more details. Do you want switch with multiple cases? Post code that you would like to see, maybe with a wrong syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Use a template:

```
template <typename T> 
bool isType(Attribute* a) {
   return dynamic_cast<T*>(a);
}
```

Then you can check the type like this:

```
bool isFirstElementAPlace = isType<Place>(*(l.begin()));
```

Comment: But what if I the types to search are in other `initializer_list<Attribute*>`?