# Existing types should be replaced, new types added to it

Tags: c++

I have one base `std::vector` and one `std::initializer_list<Attribute*>`, which is argument to function consisting of derived classes of `Attribute` class.

```
class Attribute {};
class Place : public Attribute {};
class Time : public Attribute {};
class Way: public Attribute {};

Place* place = new Place();
Time* time = new Time();
Way* way = new Way();
Place* place2 = new Place(...);
Time* time2 = new Time(...);

auto baseList = std::vector<Attribute*>({ place, time, way })

void updateBaseList(std::vector<Attribute*>& v, std::initializer_list<Attribute*> l);
```

What `updateBaseList` must do is, if the type of an element of `l` is equal to one in `baseList`, update that value in `baseList` with the one of `l`. If the type is not encountered in `baseList`, it must add to it.

Note that the type being searched for is not `Attribute*`, instead it is the derived classes.

**My attempt**

```
void updateBaseList(std::vector<Attribute*>& v, std::initializer_list<Attribute*> l) {
    bool found;
    for (auto listIt = l.begin(); listIt != l.end(); ++listIt) {
        found = false;
        for (auto attrIt = baseList.begin(); attrIt != baseList.end(); ++attrIt) {
            if (typeid(**listIt) == typeid(**attrIt)) {
                *attrIt = *listIt;
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
            baseList.push_back(*listIt);
        }
    }
}
```

But the `typeid(**listIt)` and `typeid(**attrIt)` always return `Base`.

**The goal**

If I call `updateBaseList(baseList, { time2, place2 })` baseList should be `{ place2, time2, way }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make the class hierarchy polymorphic. A good way of doing this is by adding a `virtual ~Attribute() { }` destructor:

```
struct Attribute 
{
    virtual ~Attribute() { }
};
```

Your code then [**works as expected**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/FLTo8aQ4RRk5Y6pp):

```
{
    auto baseList = std::vector<Attribute*>({ place0, time0 });

    updateBaseList(baseList, {place2, time2, way0});
    assert(baseList[0] == place2);
    assert(baseList[1] == time2);
    assert(baseList[2] == way0);
    assert(baseList.size() == 3);

    updateBaseList(baseList, {place0});
    assert(baseList[0] == place0);
    assert(baseList[1] == time2);
    assert(baseList[2] == way0);
    assert(baseList.size() == 3);
}
```

---

Unrelated, but you can make your implementation of `baseList` easier to read using C++11 range-for loops:

```
void updateBaseList(std::vector<Attribute*>& v, std::initializer_list<Attribute*> l) 
{
    for (auto& litem : l) 
    {
        bool found = false;
        for (auto& attr : baseList) 
        {
            if (typeid(*litem) != typeid(*attr)) continue;

            attr = litem;
            found = true;
            break;
        }

        if (!found) 
        {
            v.push_back(litem);
        }
    }
}
```

You can also take advantage of standard algorithms to avoid the stateful `found` variable:

```
void updateBaseList(std::vector<Attribute*>& v, std::initializer_list<Attribute*> l) 
{
    for (auto& litem : l) 
    {
        const auto found = std::find_if(std::begin(v), std::end(v), [&](Attribute* p)
                                       {
                                           return typeid(*litem) == typeid(*p);
                                       });

        if (found == std::end(v)) 
        {
            v.push_back(litem);
        }
        else 
        {
            *found = litem;
        }
    }
}
```